# Spring Cloud Stream: Spring Boot 3.x: JsonProperty, JsonIgnoreProperties behaving unexpectedly with Jackson in Message Converter

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am currently working on a Spring Boot application (version 3.0.6) and using Spring Cloud (version 2022.0.2). I have two different endpoints ("/mvc" and "/message") that use two different request objects (**DummyMessage1** and **DummyMessage2**), and I'm having some issues with Jackson's JsonProperty and JsonIgnoreProperties annotations.

In both the cases I'm looking to supress **numbers** from response and get **tokens** in response.

I have used JsonIgnoreProperties to suppress **numbers** from response.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true, value = {"numbers"}, allowSetters = true)
```

In the **`/mvc`** endpoint, everything is working as expected. I'm using **`DummyMessage1`** request object for this endpoint. The **`numbers`** field is suppressed from response as expected. Furthermore, the **`tokens`** field, is returned successfully in the JSON response and is not empty as it contains the list of tokens from the request.

The problem arises in the **`/message`** endpoint, which uses **`DummyMessage2`** to post a message to kafka. **`DummyMessage2`** is identical to **`DummyMessage1`**.

When I attempted to post a JSON to the Kafka topic, an exception was thrown:

Full stacktrace can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/cricketbackground/487eee625b1305076072164366a64635)

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [B cannot be cast to class com.example.marshaller.model.DummyMessage2 ([B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.example.marshaller.model.DummyMessage2 is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.invokeConsumer(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:990) ~[spring-cloud-function-context-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
```

Here are the request objects:

`DummyMessage1`:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true, value = {"numbers"}, allowSetters = true)
public class DummyMessage1 extends BaseRequest {

    private String numbers;

    //@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    public List<String> getTokens() {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(this.numbers)) return Collections.emptyList();
        return List.of(this.numbers.split(";\\s*"));
    }
}
```

`DummyMessage2`:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true, value = {"numbers"}, allowSetters = true)
public class DummyMessage2 extends BaseRequest {

    private String numbers;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    public List<String> getTokens() {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(this.numbers)) return Collections.emptyList();
        return List.of(this.numbers.split(";\\s*"));
    }
}
```

Next, to work around the the exception, I added the annotation **@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)** on **getTokens()** method in **DummyMessage2**. However, this did not result in the desired outcome. The JSON posted to Kafka now did not include the numbers field as required, but also, the tokens field was as empty, which is not expected.

Why is this happening? I would expect the tokens field to be populated as it is in the /mvc endpoint. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Here's repository to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/cricketbackground/marshaller

Please note for security reasons the kafka brokers and kafka zk nodes are purposefully not set in the repo.

Request Body:

```json
{
    "numbers":"12345; 3982934823; 3248923492834; 324923434"
}
```

How to use: please see [here](https://github.com/cricketbackground/marshaller#readme)

**--- Update**

Here's the simple working DummyMessage2 by adding a field for the utility getter. In the getter method the field itself is returned if it is not empty, thus retaining the field value across multiple message post hops

```java
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
    import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
    import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
    import lombok.Getter;
    import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
    import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
    import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
    import org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils;
    
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;
    
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
    @Getter
    @SuperBuilder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true, value = {"numbers"}, allowSetters = true)
    public class DummyMessage2 extends BaseRequest {
    
        private String numbers;
    
        private List<String> tokens;
    
        public List<String> getTokens() {
            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(this.tokens)) return this.tokens;
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(this.numbers)) return Collections.emptyList();
            return List.of(this.numbers.split(";\\s*"));
        }
    }
```

The other solution suggested by Yevhenii Semenov also works but requires setter method logic to be written exactly reverse of getter logic. Setter method complexity increases based on getter method. Also, if there are more fields then writing/maintaining setter methods for each field becomes a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for such behavior is in your DummyMessage configuration. You have the `String numbers` field but ignore it for Jackson. Instead, you provide the `getToken` method. So Jackson thinks that your object has only the `List<String> tokens` field and doesn't understand your bytes when you unmarshal it.

Let's look closer:

When you call your `/mvc` endpoint, there is only marshaling happening, so it works. You have the following flow:

`Request body (1)-> DummyMessage1 (2)-> Response body`

```
{
  "numbers": "6469344427; 2017586291"
}

(1) ====> 

DummyMessage1(
  String numbers = "6469344427; 2017586291"
)

(2) ====> 

{
  "tokens": [
    "6469344427",
    "2017586291"
  ]
}
```

But in your `/message` endpoint, the flow is longer:

`Request body (1)-> DummyMessage2 (2)-> Json (3)-> DummyMessage2`

And on step 3, at your `DummyMessageConsumerService`, spring tries to unmarshal `DummyMessage2` from JSON and can't do this because the Json has only the field "tokens," but there is no such field in the object.

To fix this issue:

1. Remove `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)` from `getTokens()` method
2. Add the following setter to your `DummyMessage2`

```
public void setTokens(List<String> tokens) {
    this.numbers = String.join(";", tokens);
}
```

Or you can create another DTO object like `DummyMessage3` with `List<String> tokens` instead of `String numbers`. In that case the flow will be `(1) -> DummyMessage2 (2)-> Json (3)-> DummyMessage3`.

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote this post if I helped you

Comment: I tried solutions you suggested. But it is not working. Is it possible can you share a working repository or send a pull request using my repository

Comment: @Abc.Xyz I've posted patch here: https://gist.github.com/yevheniisemenov/fee586998f608e188875465108588d60

With this patch I can see the message `Received dummy message = DummyMessage2(numbers=6469344427; 2017586291)` in logs and also json `{"tokens":["6469344427","2017586291"]}` that posted to kafka topic `this.is.output.example.topic`

Pls let me know is it work for you?

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks for your detailed answer!

Comment: I have updated OP with another simple solution. Please see update